# Error while stopping Location Sensor Firemonkey XE6

Tags: android, location, components, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I'm using a `TLocationSensor` to get the Latitude and Longitude values. My GPS is not enabled and I'm using the network location. 
Using the event `onLocationChanged` I save the values and set the property `Active` to False, but an error occurs. 
Debugging I found, inside the unit `System.Android.Sensors`, at the procedure `TUIAndroidLocationSensor.DoStop`, that the line which removes the listener does not verify if the `GPSListener` is nil and throws an exception that closes my app.
This problem does not occur when I compile for a 32-bits Windows platform, just when compiling for Android platform.

How can I solve this problem?

**Edit:**
This issue was solved on Firemonkey XE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since fixing this bug only involves modifying code in `implementation` section of `System.Android.Sensors` you can easily fix code yourself.

Copy `System.Android.Sensors.pas` into your project folder and add it to the project. Then add `nil` check in `TUIAndroidLocationSensor.DoStop` method to fix the bug.

When you compile your project Delphi will use your fixed `System.Android.Sensors` instead of default broken one.